# Error generating PDF with RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I just bought a new Mac. I've cloned my git repo onto it, and ran the following, which worked fine on the old Mac:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "statement.Rmd",
                    output_format="pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste(Payees$Payee[i], "identifying text", i, "2018_02", ".pdf", sep=''),
                    output_dir = "~/Desktop/path/to/directory")
```

I've installed tinytex on the new box, and I've run `install_tinytex()`.

Here's the error I get:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: ulem [10k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /Users/steves2018air/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr path add
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `DATA/ART/UFO_Logo.png' not found: using draft
 setting.

Error: Failed to compile XXX_UFO_CL12018_02.tex. See XXX_UFO_CL12018_02.log for more info.
```

I'm sure I just need to install something. (By the way, I ***do*** use Homebrew, but I used the .pkg installer for R).

Can anyone give me a pointer? Thanks as always.

***[Here's a link to the .log file referenced in the error msg:](https://file.io/3Xr6BL) ***

Comment: The error message says it can't find a png file "`File DATA/ART/UFO_Logo.png`"

Comment: yeah, I saw that. but the file is right there where it's supposed to be, and when I run the .Rmd file by itself, it processes just fine.

Comment: so what does `list.files(file.path('DATA','ART'))` return?

Comment: @drmariod: the file in question shows up in the result vector.

Comment: I'm adding the log file to the original post. I have no idea how to read it.

Comment: Since writing this post, I also (brew) installed basictex, which I had not done previously. But I'm still getting the error saying `DATA/ART/UFO_Logo.png' not found, while the file is definitely there. When I remove the Markdown image line entirely, the script works. Anyone?

Comment: I guess it is because the file isn’t were the Rmd expects it to be. Use ‘getwd()’ and the ‘list.files(“DATA/ART/“, full.names=TRUE)’ command within you Rmd, comment out the problematic line and update your question with the output!